# Is a comma required when we begin a sentence with a gerund?

Tags: punctuation

Is there a rule that states if a comma is needed in the following case:
Doing this, does that?
The following sentences made me ponder on it:
Clicking on a job within a project(,) opens the page where the button is located.
Cloning a job(,) allows you to set new settings.

Comment: No, those commas you’ve placed in brackets shouldn’t be used.

Comment: *Running can be strenuous.* There's a gerund without a comma.

Comment: @JasonBassford I really struggle with gerunds! I thought a gerund had to function as a verb in the sentence (as well as functioning as a noun), but in your example there's no verb function. If it was *running a race* (takes an object) or *running quickly* (modified by an adverb), it would indicate a verb function. Am I misunderstanding this? Is there a useful resource you rely on that might guide me?

Answer (score 2):

For the example sentences, **no**.

In general, it depends on what role the gerund phrase takes.

If the gerund begins a phrase functioning as an adverb, then **yes** on the comma.

*Reading your sentences, I do not advise using a comma.*

[Source for using a comma after an introductory adverb phrase](https://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/commas_intro.htm)

If the gerund begins a phrase that is the subject of the sentence, as in your examples, then **no** comma.

*Beginning a sentence with a gerund does not always require one to use a comma.*

In your examples, the entire phrase before each "(,)" is the subject of the respective sentence.